# Determine the left offset of a click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Say you have an image that is 200px wide. Is there a way to determine how far from the left of the image you clicked? For example if you clicked in the dead center you would get 100. I tried using something like ui.position.left but couldn't get that to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, get the X position of the image. Next, use the event information to get the X position of the click event.

Once you have those two, it's simple math to get the result:

```
$('#yourImg').click(function(e){
    var imageLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    var clickLeft = e.pageX;
    var howFarFromLeft = clickLeft - imageLeft;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the mouse coordinates at the time of the click (*by using the event of the click, `event.pageX`, `event.pageY`*). Then find the location of the image in the body. and subtract it from the mouseposition..

The result would be the coordinates inside the image.. [Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5A3w2/)